# Setting Django secret key in environment variable fails due to special character

Tags: django, heroku, virtualenv

I'm trying to set a Django secret key as a local environment variable in my `venv/bin/activate`.

But the key has a "(" in it and I get a venv error `-bash: venv/bin/activate: line 85: syntax error near unexpected token ')'`

I'm a bit stuck here.  How can I set this Key as a local environment variable so that it accepts these special characters?

Comment: can you change some of the other characters of the key and show it here?

Comment: Thanks.  How about this:  export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=1t789b5)q@548r!2@mjj9k$ms!joubcpya#yts45n@s&pq28l8

Comment: Put it as a string. `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY='1t789b5)q@548r!2@mjj9k$ms!joubcpya#yts45n@s&pq28l8'`

Comment: That was easy.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Surround the string with single or double quotes. For longer strings (more than one line), you can use single or double quotes in sets of three. For more information and examples, refer to  http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html.