# Creating .env file on the root of the project

Tags: django, python-decouple

I am trying to download a Django project from github and one of the requirements is:"As the project uses python-decouple you will need to create a file named .env on the root of the project with three values, as following:

```
DEBUG=True
SECRET_KEY='mys3cr3tk3y'
DATABASE_URL='postgres://u_bootcamp:p4ssw0rd@localhost:5432/bootcamp
```

"

1.What(where) is the root part of the project, is it part of the project where are settings?

2.What kind of file should .env be?(python package I suppose)

3.Should name of the file be simply .env(or something.env)?

4.Is .env file going to be imported in settings file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. What(where) is the root part of the project, is it part of the project where are settings?

   - Where your `manage.py` file is (that is your project root directory).
2. What kind of file should .env be? (python package I suppose)

   - `.env` is a text file not a package.
3. Should name of the file be simply .env (or something.env)?

   - Just `.env`
4. Is .env file going to be imported in settings file?

   - No need to import, `python-decouple` automatically picks variables from there.

Read more about [Where the settings data are stored?](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-decouple#where-the-settings-data-are-stored) and [Usage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-decouple#usage) of `python-decouple`.

Comment: also, you need to mention that in .env the values should not be in quotes

Comment: Late response @NikosVitaTopiko, but does that include when the `SECRET_KEY` includes `#` character? For instance, if `SECRET_KEY=ABCD123#45`. The query here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236850/setting-django-secret-key-in-environment-variable-fails-due-to-special-character suggests to add quotes.

Comment: So how do you add .env to your server since it will be in .gitignore

Comment: @Martins Server should not be using `.env`, you should inject those environment variables directly (e.g. code deployment)

Comment: @Aamir Adnan I'm using python decouple adding my API keys to .bash_profile, will decouple config find the file?