# How does a .env file relate to Python / Django?

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I'm pretty new to Django / Python, and I'm trying to figure out how a `.env` file relates to a Django project.

Example `.env`:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres_user@db:xxxx/postgres_db
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=spare.settings.dev
SECRET_KEY=example
```

I did manage to find [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416029/creating-env-file-on-the-root-of-the-project), which gives some information, but was hoping for a bit more.

- Do all Django projects have a `.env` file?
- Do non-Django python projects have a `.env` file, or is it generally a Django-related thing?
- Where is the `.env` file typically being called from? In other words, how does the rest of the project know that the .env file exists?

Comment: `.env` file is very very simple ianswered here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63446561/10620360](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63446561/10620360)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can only guess because we don't have access to your actual environment.

The `.env` file may be a container manager thing or something from libraries like [python-decouple](https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple) - for practical effects the `.env` will be used to populate the environment variables when the container "boots" or will be used to fill instance settings.

There is a common pattern made popular by the [Twelve-Factor app](https://12factor.net/): the item III is "Store config in the environment". Then in the `settings.py` file you use the `KEY = os.environ.get('KEY', 'defaul_value')`. The idea is to separate instance settings from project settings from code.

Comment: Oh right. Docker is involved, which I also don't know much about. That helps. Thanks. I'll mark this correct when I can.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416029/creating-env-file-on-the-root-of-the-project?noredirect=1&lq=1