# How to robustly set Django secret key as environment variable

Tags: django, environment-variables, django-settings

My Django project's secret key contains special characters such as `#`, `@`, `^`, `*` etc. I'm trying to set this as an env variable at `/etc/environment`.

I include the following in the file:

```
export SECRET_KEY='zotpbek!*t_abkrfdpo!*^@#plg6qt-x6(%dg)9p(qoj_r45y8'
```

I.e. I included single quotes around the string since it contains special characters (also prescribed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236850/setting-django-secret-key-in-environment-variable-fails-due-to-special-character) SO post). I exit the file and do `source /etc/environment`. Next I type `env` in the terminal: `SECRET__KEY` correctly shows.

I log out and log back in. I type `env` again.

This time `SECRET_KEY` still shows, but is cut off beyond the `@` character. It's excluding everything beyond (and including) the `#` character.

How do I fix this issue? Trying with double quotes didn't alleviate anything either. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

---

p.s. I'm aware environment variables don't support access control; there's a bunch of reasons not to set the Django secret key as an env var. For the purposes of this ques, let's put that on the back burner.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Django problem per se.  According to this question [Escape hash mark (#) in /etc/environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97736/escape-hash-mark-in-etc-environment) you *can't* use a "#" in `/etc/environment`.

I would recommend that you keep regenerating your secret key until you get one without #s -- that should fix the problem.  [Django Extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_extensions.html) has a command `generate_secret_key`  for this. The side effect of changing the secret key is that current sessions will become invalid, that is, unless you are using it other places in your application.

Comment: Then why did the secret key display correctly after being set initially?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to generate one using python3 in you linux terminal with following inline script:

```
python3 -c 'import random; print("".join([random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@%^&*-_") for i in range(50)]))'
```

this will generate secret key without unsafe characters

Answer (score 0):

As per the `django-environ` documention you can use unsafe characters in .env file.

https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#tips

To use unsafe characters you have to encode with `urllib.parse.encode` before you set into .env file.

`Example:- admin#123 = admin%28123`