# Must my django secret key be 50 chars long

Tags: python, sql, django

I thought the secret key was just something like a password, so I changed it.
Now I found out that it is used to make hashes and that kind of stuff.
So can I just type anything I want in the secret key field, or is a special algorythm needed?

#### And must my secret key be 50 chars long or can it be of any length?

**Thx for your help and stay healthy!**

Comment: There are tools to generate a new one if you want to

Answer (score 0):

according to Django docs and security [checks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/checks/):

> **security.W009**: Your SECRET_KEY has **less than 50 characters**, **less than
> 5 unique characters**, or it’s prefixed with 'django-insecure-'
> indicating that it was generated automatically by Django. Please
> generate a long and random SECRET_KEY, otherwise many of Django’s
> security-critical features will be vulnerable to attack

So, Your SECRET_KEY should be at least 50 characters in length and could contain a random mix of letters, digits, and symbols.

But plz keep in mind, that for special characters (e.g. hash mark #) you may face issues in Virtual environments, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236850/setting-django-secret-key-in-environment-variable-fails-due-to-special-character). So the best practice is to generate SECRET_KEY with special tools, e.g. [Django Extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_extensions.html) with a command `generate_secret_key`